# Lock picking technique

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-3

So I've tried this twice now and it's taken me about 5 minutes each time and it feels way too random.
The instructions say "Move the mouse left and right" so am I supposed to wiggle it? .. and the same with the "Up and down".

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but could someone explain how this is supposed to work so I can try and get it down for the future.

Comment: In case somebody from xbox gets here then I should note that when you are rotating sticks you need to do it slowly since if you do it too fast you won't get the feedback and you can just happily keep going round in circles. It may be speed of movement is relevant in PC version too but I've only played on xbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to wiggle the mouse.

The way I do these is to, for each stage (left and right, up and down) to pick a direction and slowly move the mouse in it until either the next stage unlocks or the progress on the current stage resets, in which case I try the other direction.

This has never taken me more than a minute to complete so far.

Comment: Having done some more lock picking I can say that you must be pro. I'm still finding this is taking me about 2-3 minutes per chest.

Comment: You're trying to line up the tumblers - you just have to hit the sweet spot.  I can't speak for PC versions but on console this is exactly like the frequency scanner from Arkham Asylum.

Comment: @David You might need to move the mouse slower than you currently are, I've found that slowing down my mouse movement has made the process faster for me.

Comment: @StevenCunningham Thanks, I'll try it with my mouse on a lower DPI setting too which might help

Comment: "or the progress on the current stage resets," 

How can you tell when your progress "resets"?  It just keeps turning in a circle for me.